# Преобразование массива с одинаковыми ключами

Tags: php, массивы

Привет всем, ребята что то не получается преобразовать массив в нужную структуру, не получилось как то применить array_push. Или алгоритм не правильный ну короче тупик.
Есть массив:

```
$array = Array(
    'NAME' => Array
        (
            'TOUR' => Array
                (
                    '0' => 'Тур 1',
                    '1' => 'Тур 2'
                ),

            'TRANSFER' => Array
                (
                    '0' => 'Трансфер 1',
                    '1' => 'SD XA'
                )

        ),

    'TYPE' => Array
        (
            'TOUR' => Array
                (
                    '0' => 'VIP',
                    '1' => 'STANDART'
                ),

            'TRANSFER' => Array
                (
                    '0' => 'HHS',
                    '1' => 'GGG'
                )

        ),

    'PERIOD' => Array
        (
            'TOUR' => Array
                (
                    '0' => Array
                        (
                            '0' => '14.01.2018',
                            '1' => '17.01.2018'
                        ),

                    '1' => Array
                        (
                            '0' => '07.01.2018',
                            '1' => '16.01.2018'
                        )

                ),

            'TRANSFER' => Array
                (
                    '0' => Array
                        (
                            '0' => '29.01.2018',
                            '1' => '29.01.2018'
                        ),

                    '1' => Array
                        (
                            '0' => '29.01.2018',
                            '1' => '29.01.2018'
                        )

                )

        )
);
```

А нужен такой результат:

```
$result = Array
(
    'TOUR' => Array
        (
            'NAME' => Array
                (
                    '0' => 'Тур 1',
                    '1' => 'Тур 2'
                ),

            'TYPE' => Array
                (
                    '0' => 'VIP',
                    '1' => 'STANDART'
                ),
            'PERIOD' => Array
                (
                    '0' => Array
                        (
                            '0' => '14.01.2018',
                            '1' => '17.01.2018'
                        ),

                    '1' => Array
                        (
                            '0' => '07.01.2018',
                            '1' => '16.01.2018'
                        )

                )

        ),

    'TRANSFER' => Array
        (
            'NAME' => Array
                (
                    '0' => 'Трансфер 1',
                    '1' => 'SD XA'
                ),
            'TYPE' => Array
                (
                    '0' => 'HHS',
                    '1' => 'GGG'
                ),
            'PERIOD' => Array
                (
                    '0' => Array
                        (
                            '0' => '29.01.2018',
                            '1' => '29.01.2018'
                        ),

                    '1' => Array
                        (
                            '0' => '29.01.2018',
                            '1' => '29.01.2018'
                        )

                )

        )

);
```

Что то придумал, но он сохраняет только последний массив, надо что то добавить.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key_ => $value_) {
        $result[$key_] = [$key => $value_];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = Array();
foreach($array as $key1 => $value1)
{
    foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) 
    {
        foreach($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
            $result[$key2][$key1][$key3] = $value3;
        }
    }
}
```